# How to dual boot Fedora 14 on Macbook Pro 15" without CD/DVD, ie. .iso file bootable from external HDD

Tags: external-hard-drive, macbook, fedora, iso-image

I have done quite a bit of looking around and have not been able to find a single walkthrough for doing this.  I have:

MacBook Pro 15" with 20GB partition (of 500GB) which I want to install fedora ON
1TB External HDD which I want to be able to install fedora FROM
Fedora i386 DVD .iso file

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Installing [from an ISO on a hard drive](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/s1-begininstall-hd-x86.html) isn't hard, but you still [need to boot the install somehow](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/sn-install-diff-source-x86.html). Try a [USB key boot](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/Making_Minimal_Boot_Media.html#Making_Minimal_Boot_Media-UEFI).